# Wrapping async code with suspendCoroutine vs sync code with suspending builder

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm looking for suspending way writing to file. I found this [example from Kotlin/coroutines-examples](https://github.com/Kotlin/coroutines-examples/blob/master/examples/io/io.kt) which is wraping `AsynchronousFileChannel` with `suspendCoroutine { ... }` but I'm wondering if there is any benefit from wrapping synchronous call with `withContext(IO){}`

```
private suspend fun File.writeTextAsync(text: String): Unit = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
        val aFileChannel = AsynchronousFileChannel.open(toPath(), StandardOpenOption.WRITE)
        val byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(text.toByteArray())
        aFileChannel.write(
            byteBuffer,
            0,
            Unit,
            object : java.nio.channels.CompletionHandler<Int, Unit> {
                override fun completed(bytesRead: Int, attachment: Unit) {
                    cont.resume(Unit)
                }

                override fun failed(exception: Throwable, attachment: Unit) {
                    cont.resumeWithException(exception)
                }
            })
    }
```

vs.

```
withContext(IO) { File(...).writeText(text) }
```

Comment: The benefit is the same as in any other case, reusing a single thread to do many concurrent IO ops.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik right, but my question really is about the difference between those two approaches.

Comment: I just pointed out the difference: creating N threads to run N concurrent IO ops vs. having a single thread execute them all without compromising concurrency. If there is any other difference you have in mind, it is a consequence of this fact.

Comment: So the first approach creates new thread for each new call ? Could you proof that ? My diving down starts [here](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk7u/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/nio/channels/AsynchronousFileChannel.java#L241) and ends up [here](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/master/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/DefaultFileSystemProvider.java). Documentation says that the channel is "is associated with default thread pool to which tasks are submitted to handle I/O events", which doesn't fulfill my curiosity

Comment: No, the _second_ approach creates a new thread for each concurrent blocking IO call. It's easy to prove, `withContext(IO) { (1..64).forEach { Thread.sleep(1000) } }`. If this executes in a single second, you know it must have created 64 threads. If still not convinced, use VisualVM or the "thread snapshot" feature in IntelliJ to see them. I used 64 because that's the default max IO thread pool size. You can change it with a [system property](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-i-o_-p-a-r-a-l-l-e-l-i-s-m_-p-r-o-p-e-r-t-y_-n-a-m-e.html).

Comment: Sorry the example should have said `runBlocking { (1..64).forEach { launch(IO) { Thread.sleep(1000) } } }`. In IntelliJ's thread dump I can see "_64 similar threads (sleeping)_".